# How do I create series of div and make them accessible for jquery to modify them after a while?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create some DIV from javascript. I don't know how many I will need to create, but I will need to change the back-color of it after a while.

I'm using jQuery in my project. So if it's easier the solution can use jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $myDiv = $('<div />');
```

This will create a div inside the variable `$myDiv`.

You can change any property of it later on, and you can even add it to your page, like:

```
$myDiv.css('background-color', '#FFF').appendTo('#anotherDiv');
```

Answer (score 1):

Give them a class name that you can later refer to.

Answer (score 1):

Give them a class name, and then refer to it in jQuery like so:

```
<div class="something">Hello</div>
<div class="something">Hi</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div.something').css('background-color', 'white'); // Or whatever
});
</script>
```